# Put multiple div on bottom of div

Tags: html, css

How can I put the three different div (red, yello, green) on the bottom of the div every time i try to move it?

```
.torre{
height: 500px;
width: 300px;
border: black solid 2px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
top: 100%;
}
```

[This is what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4fs0.png)

Comment: not clear what you're asking ?

Comment: *on the bottom of the every time* ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link you provided, I'm assuming you are wanting to replicate the contents of the `div` on the left with the middle and right div's. If that's the case, you will just need to copy the `div` that looks the way you currently want it and set the three containers containing the three block sizes to `display: inline-block;`

Below is an example that I quickly put together that you can reference and modify based on what you would like. I added extra `margin` around the elements just to help show the setup and added borders around all of the containers.

Hope this helps. Next time try providing more detail showing everything you've tried.

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: padding-box;
}

.main_container {
    border: 2px solid #0000ff;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 75%;
}

.box_container1 {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5% 5% 5% 0;
}

    .box_container1 .box1 {
        border: 2px solid green;
        margin: 5%;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 10% auto;
    }

    .box_container1 .box2 {
        border: 2px solid pink;
        margin: 10% auto;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .box_container1 .box3 {
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        margin: 10% auto;
        width: 75%;
    }

.box_container2 {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5% 5% 5% 0;
}

    .box_container2 .box1 {
        border: 2px solid green;
        margin: 5%;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 10% auto;
    }

    .box_container2 .box2 {
        border: 2px solid pink;
        margin: 10% auto;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .box_container2 .box3 {
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        margin: 10% auto;
        width: 75%;
    }

.box_container3 {
    border: 2px solid #ff0000;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

    .box_container3 .box1 {
        border: 2px solid green;
        margin: 5%;
        width: 25%;
        margin: 10% auto;
    }

    .box_container3 .box2 {
        border: 2px solid pink;
        margin: 10% auto;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .box_container3 .box3 {
        border: 2px solid yellow;
        margin: 10% auto;
        width: 75%;
    }

.group {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/so_help.css" type="text/css">
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
        
        <div class="main_container group">
            <div class="box_container1">
                <div class="box1">Box1</div>
                <div class="box2">Box2</div>
                <div class="box3">Box3</div>
            </div>

            <div class="box_container2">
                <div class="box1">Box1</div>
                <div class="box2">Box2</div>
                <div class="box3">Box3</div>
            </div>

            <div class="box_container3">
                <div class="box1">Box1</div>
                <div class="box2">Box2</div>
                <div class="box3">Box3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
 </body>
</html>
```